# How to specify Android notification channel for FCM push messages in Android 8

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, notification-channel

Our app now has `targetSdkVersion 26` (Android 8) and the app uses FCM push notifications.

As [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) prescribes I updated the FCM client library to version 11.2.0:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
}
```

With this FCM client library update the FCM notifications started to appear on Android devices. Good, but when app is in background it's system who processes the FCM message, so it uses the default Android notification channel named "Miscellaneous", which is not what we want (we have other notification channels and "Miscellaneous" sounds confusing in that list).

As [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) says there is a way to specify default notification channel for FCM messages:

> (Optional) Within the application component, metadata elements to set
>   a default icon, color and **notification channel** (new in Android O) for
>   notifications. Android uses these values whenever incoming messages do
>   not explicitly set icon, color or **notification_channel**.

However there is no code sample shown (samples are shown only for icon and color). So I just found by googling a sample in [Firebase Cloud Messaging Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) on github:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

But it does not work - FCM notifications still appear within the "Miscellaneous" channel. And I see in the logs:

> W/FirebaseMessaging: Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in
>   AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.

Of course, I tried to reinstall the app. Still having the issue.

Well, ideally there should be some way to specify notification channel(s) on back-end at the moment of sending the messages. The FCM dev console, which allows to test sending, now has such an option in UI:

[image]

And it works fine. However our back-end uses Java Amazon SNS API and I have no idea if that API allows to specify Android notification channel when sending a message (because it'a new Android feature, and Amazon needs time to adopt it). So setting a default notification channel in `AndroidManifest.xml` would be a valid workaround for now, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you create the string value `default_notification_channel_id `?

Comment: Of course, I did.

Comment: In you post you write ".default_notification_channel", but it should be "..default_notification_channel*_id*"

Comment: FYI, [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047344/199364).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

> **android_channel_id** The notification's channel id (new in Android O).
>
> The app must create a channel with this ID before any notification
>   with this key is received.
>
> If you don't send this key in the request, or if the channel id
>   provided has not yet been created by your app, FCM uses the channel id
>   specified in your app manifest.

Try to include `android_channel_id` in json you are about to post to fcm. I have no idea why manifest value is not working for you. Try to just add channel to your request, you should get the same effect as from Firebase Console.

Edit: I just realized you are asking for Amazon client integration. Maybe you are able to build json request manually then (I don't know much about Amazon services, sorry).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to use `android_channel_id` param via Amazon SNS console (just by adding it to JSON payload). This is even better than default notification channel in AndroidManifest.xml, so I am no longer bothered with why it did not work. :)

Comment: how can i create **android_channel_id**

Comment: The cited link points to a section marked Legacy HTTP Server Protocol, but the main protocol section makes no mention of **android_channel_id**

Comment: @VitKhudenko may I ask what exactly you addded to your json file? thanks

Comment: @rosualin, the `android_channel_id` param with the string id value which is specific to my application.

Comment: What happens if we do not create any notification channel?I read that FCM creates "default notification channel with basic settings".Does that mean I do not have to create a basic notification channel in the app manifest?

Comment: Have you even read docs? There will be default channel created in this case.

Comment: android_channel_id will cause bad request:
instead, use channel_id
credits to li2 answer

Comment: @user1209216 Kindly share any example code in json format of notification to elaborate your answer, will be very helpful to all of us. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18):

FCM has migrated to [HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1):

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{{projectId}}/messages:send
```

`android_channel_id` will cause bad request:

```
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
"fieldViolations": [
  {
    "field": "message.notification",
    "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"android_channel_id\" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field."
  }
```

The correct payload should be:

```
{
    "message": {
        "token": "{{deviceToken}}",
        "notification": {
            "body": "This is an FCM notification message hello 23",
            "title": "FCM Message",
            "image": "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/au_moviesshowcase_mulan_poster_r_2_54011055.jpeg?region=0,0,960,1420"
        },
        "android": {
          "notification": {
            "channel_id": "channel_id_1"
          }
        },
        "data": {
            "key1": "42",
            "key2": "sent by 21"
        }
    }
}
```

see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#resource:-message

Comment: @VitKhudenko But the problem is `onMessageReceived` won't be getting called when App is in the background if the payload contains `notification` part, which means you cannot put channel id in the payload if you need `onMessageReceived` to be called no matter App is in foreground or background. Totally have no idea how to make both of them working. Lol

Comment: Hey li2, I have the exact same situation. Did you or somebody else got it working?

Comment: @GuilhermeRamos you can add an extra key `"channel_id"` in `"data"` part, then parse the data payload `remoteMessage.data` on `onMessageReceived` callback, then you're able to do whatever you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's ok. But what about the app is not "running", it's in the background?

Comment: Finally worked after hours of searching, Thanks, man :)

Comment: Hey, did anyone find a solution?

Comment: A data only payload where you parse the fields however you want and set the channel to whatever you want, and then post the notification yourself, seems to be the answer. A data only payload should call `onMessageReceived` when in the foreground or the background

Answer (score 11):

Depend on this resource : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Here Payload look like :

```
{
   "to":"$device_token"
   "notification":{
      "title":"Title",
      "body":"Here Body",
      "android_channel_id":"$channel_id", // For Android >= 8
      "channel_id":"$channel_id", // For Android Version < 8
      "image": "https://xxxxx.com/xxxxx.jpeg"
   },
   "data":{},
   "priority":"normal"
}
```

Comment: thats what am searching for , y'all guys , check this answer code comments , hes specify `android_channel_id` & `channel_id`