# Firebase: How to set default notification channel in Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

How to set **default** notification channel for *notification messages* that come when an app is in the background? By default, these messages use "Miscellaneous" channel.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As you can see [here in the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), you need to add the following metadata element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` within the application component:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

This default channel will be used when notification message has no specified channel, or if the channel provided has not yet been created by the app.

Comment: where is this **default_notification_channel_id**

Comment: in your strings.xml file, put `<string name=“default_notification_channel_id”>Channel ID</string>`, you can take a look at this post for more information: https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c

Comment: What happens if we do not create even a default notification channel like above in the app manifest?

Comment: @user1261913 I don't think setting your own default notification channel is necessary. The docs state: "FCM provides a default notification channel with basic settings. **If you prefer** to create and use your own default channel, set default_notification_channel_id to the ID of your notification channel object as shown;"

Comment: Surely the string "Channel ID" defined in the strings res must tie up with SOMETHING SOMEWHERE?

Comment: If creating the `strings.xml` file, be sure you format it correctly with the `xml version` and `resources` tag or you'll get build errors. See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

Comment: after `<string name=` make sure to use normal quotes `"` instead of curved quotation `“`/`”`

Comment: You may refer to this post regarding how to create a notification channel in Flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67543703/11204120

Comment: where this channel is checked? like the NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID

Comment: Worked for me for the debug build, but doesn't seem to work in release. Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to have registered a channel using `NotificationManager` `CreateNotificationChannel`.

This example uses c# in Xamarin, but is broadly applicable elsewhere

```
private void ConfigureNotificationChannel()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
        // support library). There is no need to create a notification
        // channel on older versions of Android.
        return;
    }

    var channelId = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.default_notification_channel_id);
    var channelName = "Urgent";
    var importance = NotificationImportance.High;

    //This is the default channel and also appears in the manifest
    var chan = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);

    chan.EnableVibration(true);
    chan.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;

    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);

}
```

This channel should be unique eg *com.mycompany.myapp.urgent*

You then add a reference to a string inside the *application* tag in the *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
</application>
```

Finally, setup the string in *strings.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id">com.mycompany.myapp.urgent</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me in release mode, only in debug. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add Cordova config.xml

```
<widget 
... 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
...>



 <platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="application" mode="merge">
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="res/values/strings.xml" parent="/*">
      <string name="default_notification_channel_id">urgent_alert</string>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

as my cases i already added

- metadata on AndroidManifest.xml
- Android Notification Channel on MainActivity.kt
- `<string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>` on values/string.xml

then i figured out that my running devices at that time is on Night/Dark mode, so i need to copy `values/string.xml` to `values-night/string.xml` (create one if doesn't exist) then the local notifications will appear

so between the light and dark mode we need to adjust independently for the values