# How do you specify a default notification channel ID in the application manifest?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Android Oreo introduces notification channels, but the documentation for how to specify a default notification channel in the application manifest seems to be patchy to nonexistent.

How do you specify a default notification channel ID in the application manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a default channel ID from the manifest cannot be done with standard notification channels, it only applies to Firebase notifications: [Firebase: How to set default notification channel in Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047343/firebase-how-to-set-default-notification-channel-in-android-app)