# How to change the notification settings in android apps?

Tags: java, android

How can I switch all these settings on programmatically?

I noticed when you install WhatsApp they are all switched on in the beginning(look at the image below).

But I can not find a way to turn them on programmatically.

[image]

Here is how I send **notifications**:

```
 private void sendNotification(Intent intent){

    Context context = NotificationService.this;

    //open the activity after the notification is clicked
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);


    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setTicker("Notification")
            .setContentTitle("Important Message")
            .setContentText("This is an example of a push notification using a Navigation Manager")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);



    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    //These are necessary for the notification to pop up
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound);
        builder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);
    }

    //after android O we must use notification channels
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        String channelId = "Your_channel_id";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Reminder to remind to review your notes",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        if(alarmSound != null){
            AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build();

            channel.setSound(alarmSound,att);
        }


        channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setDescription("Hello Dear friends"); //this is to test what this is

        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{300, 300, 300});
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setChannelId(channelId);
    }


    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);


}
```

I also added this permission to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

**Update:**
Using this code on the emulator, I get the heads-up notification. But on my Xiaomi device, there is no heads-up notification. It just appears on the status bar. If I manually turn on the floating notification (which you can see in the photo) then I will get heads-up notification. But they are switched off by default. When you install Whatsapp they are all switched on.
Is that a kind of privilege for Whatsapp as it is famout? or is there a way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42597698/9365212  this might help you

Comment: Thank, unfortunately there is no accepted answer in that thread

Comment: @Keivan.k Hi sir, have you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Dear. Unfortunately not

Comment: @Keivan.k this question is not enough attention, we need to improve it.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. This is an important issue. But how?

Comment: @Keivan.k have you found the solution?

Comment: @ticherhaz Unfortunately not

Comment: @Keivan.k I have found some comments stated that, only Xiaomi devices have this problem

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I can't say that for sure, even though Xiaomi is a very popular device. I Myself have Xiaomi and it's a paint not supporting Xiaomi devices.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you install a app, the system register's default notification channel (on low priority) that doesn't support head up notification by default, it's turned off. You can't control that.

But what you can do it create your own notification channel with highest priority and then register it on app run once.

After that just pass the channel Id with your notification builder so that system shows the head's up notification which you want.

More information can be found here https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: As you can see I did create a channel Id with PRIORIRTY_HIGH but that doesn't work on my Xiaomi device. And the question is how to set the settings the way Whatsapp does. To send headsup notification I need to have "floating notification" turned on

Comment: You're only creating a notification with highest priority payload but the system is selecting the default notification channel which buy default is on low mode. First you need to create a custom notification channel and then you need to set that notification channel as your default channel for the notification in your android manifest file. Kindly care to read when someone give solution and try atleast.

Comment: How do you declare it in the manifest? I don't completely understand your solution, because when I check the notification settings, it shows that it's priority is set to high. But still no heads-up notification.

Comment: based on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591282/how-do-you-specify-a-default-notification-channel-id-in-the-application-manifest) you can only set default channel for Firebase channel, not regular notifications.

Comment: Then you can simply pass the channel ID with your notification builder.

Comment: That's what I did. Check the 3rd line from the end!!

Comment: Dude sorry but I can't help you understand when you don't want to understand. I hope somebody could help you.

Comment: Your solution is not clear. You said to declare it in the manifest but you don't have a code for it. You said pass the channel Id, and that's exactly what I did in my code. Maybe you should explain your solution in a better way. Thanks for you cooperation anyway.

Comment: I read your whole answer and all of your comments carefully. None of them answer my questions. . If you can explain your solution in a clean way please do so. Otherwise let's not continue this discussion

Comment: I'll try to give you an example with a complete project asap 

Comment: That would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried for this but unable to set these settings programmatically. Instead of this I have used following method to open notification settings screen to enable notification sounds/vibration.

```java
 private void openNotificationSettingsForApp(String channelId) {
        // Links to this app's notification settings.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && channelId!=null){
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID,channelId);
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());
        }
        intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. it's a good alternative. I also couldn't find any solution. However, when you install Whatsapp they are all switched on.

Comment: when you are creating the notification channel for your notification you can enable those according to the priority of the notification

Comment: How? There is no properties in the documentation that is supposed to enable those settings.

Comment: see this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#importance
and also see these constants https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT