# Navigation is not working in Firebase Messaging Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

The screen is not navigating in `onLaunh()`and `onResume()` methods of firebase messaging, And I tried to show local notification to navigate scree but still fail.

My Payload

> onResume payload======{notification: {}, data: {notification_type: VideoCalling, role:
>   ROLE_CONSILIER_CARIERA, google.original_priority: high,
>   google.sent_time: 1576478554401, google.delivered_priority: high,
>   appointment:
>   {"video_duration":"0","mod_desfasurare":"3","observatii_destinatar":"","initiator":"204","observatii_initiator":"chdh","data_sfarsit_programare":"2019-12-14
>   12:00:00","created_by_user":"204","data_inceput_programare":"2019-12-14
>   11:00:00","status_destinatar":"1","status_initiator":"1","descriere":"chhxsh","destinatar":"246","tip":"0","id":"241","data_adaugarii":"2019-12-13
>   15:56:39","titlu":"test 13 dc","disponibilitate":"346"}, body: Apelul
>   video programat este activ acum pentru student, title: Escouniv,
>   click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id:
>   0:1576478554409777%dd3b8f6edd3b8f6e, collapse_key: com.sys.escouniv,
>   google.ttl: 2419200, from: 347273381579, id: 50, status: done}}

```
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
        Log.e('onLaunch====== ', msg);
        Log.e('onLaunch data====== ', msg['data']);
       // showNotification(msg);
        _navigateToItemDetail(msg);
      /*  Future.delayed(
            const Duration(seconds: 4),
                () =>    Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new StudentTutorials(user:UserType.Student,)),
        ));*/

      },
```

@Anand Saga [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025164/firebase-messaging-onresume-and-onlaunch-not-working) I followed the same thing ,
As i understand why I'm getting key `notification` null but in `onMessage` i'm getting `notification` with title and body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one bool flag and set it true after build complete like this

`WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){ flag = true; });`

And use this timer inside your `onLaunch`

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer){
  if(flag) {
    timer.cancel();
    doNavigation();
  }
});
```

Comment: let me try. but I have already tried to use global state and future delayed

Comment: Your code is reaching me inside in `Timer` but i stuck in ` Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator` I'm trying to rid off from this situation.

Comment: Could you please shared proper example, not able to understand where should we add this code and how they communicate with each other. Thank you in advance.