# How to start specific screen when notification appear in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) for notification, everyting is work fine.
I have a video calling screen I want to start this screen on notification when app in background.
It's working fine when application in foreground.

here is my firebase integration code:

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Map data = message["data"];
        if (data.isNotEmpty){
          Fcm.startRinging(data);
        } else {
          showNotification(title: "Message", body: "Telemedicine");
        }
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Map data = message["data"];
        print("OnLaunch::: $message");
        showNotification(title: "Message", body: "Telemedicine Call");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Fcm.myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Map data = message["data"];
        print("onResume::: $message");

      },
    );
```

Here I handle payload notification when application in background:

```
class Fcm{
  static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("hello"+message.toString());

    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
      // Handle data message
      final dynamic data = message['data'];
      await startRinging(data);
      print(data);
    }

    if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
      // Handle notification message
      final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
      print(notification);
    }

    return Future<void>.value();
    // Or do other work.
  }


  static void startRinging(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data) async {
    print("start");
    String docName = data["DoctorName"];
    String docImage = data["DoctorImage"];
    String room = data["RoomName"];
    String token = data["PatientToken"];
    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> CallResponse(
        docName: docName,
        docImage: docImage,
        token: token,
        roomName: room
    ));
    <Here I am trying to start next route but i don't have BuildContext>
//    await Navigator.push(context, route);
  }
}
```

Comment: I will evaluate it and will let you know after my working hours.

Comment: @MDavid let me know when you free.

Comment: I feel you are going on wrong direction you have to Use VOIP protocol i-e CallKit etc , for incoming calls otherwise it will feel like re-inventing the wheel, It need background mode for waiting of Incoming calls  and msgs. otherwise your user will first click on notification then that notification will load the app with active incoming call screen. so its better to use what already have beed developed by wonderful developers.
here is an example please review it https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkeep#-example-tab-

Comment: On push notification i want just start my a screen.

Comment: but there is no any BuildContext when app in background and killed.

Comment: yes you are right for that VOIP protocol take place , that is responsible for activating the app and use the default call screen as well

Comment: The purpose of Push notification is to inform the user about some message, it will never awake the app automatically when app has been kill by user or OS. App will be awake when user tap on notification thats the only way to load the app through notification. I am not very expert in Android but in iOS it will not work

Answer (score 1):

The notification received from [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) while the app is in background will be received in the notification tray and the message can be handled on [onBackgroundMessage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages). You can run functions in `onBackgroundMessage()`, but this can't launch the app. The user needs to [interact](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) with the notification received to launch the app. The VOIP protocol that you're handling should be the one managing the app launch when an incoming call is received.