# Flutter Firebase Messagings Notification is not getting payload

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
firebaseMessaging.configure(onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
  print(" onLaunch called");
  return;
}, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
  print(" onResume called");
  return;
}, onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
  print(" onMessage called");
  return;
});
```

which is my code in inistate function of my main screen.

When the app is not on the foreground ,if I send notification through the cloud messaging, I am
getting notification successfully. However when my app is on the launch, I am not not getting nay console log from my code.

what I am expecting that code, when my app is on launch , I had to get " onLaunch called" Console log message.

But I am not getting anything. I think that the configure function is not working properly.

Is there anyone who knows why this kind of problem happens?

[image]
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps check the logs to see if the request was sent?

Comment: Nothing showing up on debug console... I am using with VScode.

Comment: you try to put a data key in your payload? Like this:  data: {
                            title: "title here",
                            alert: "message here"
                        }

Comment: for now I am sending notification manually through the cloud messaging in firebase website. But I am not getting any payload through that,,, so frustrating , I can not go next step without solving this problem

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025164/firebase-messaging-onresume-and-onlaunch-not-working

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596533/12037365

Comment: Can you please show us your notification data?

Comment: Thanks for the comment on my question ! I solved my problem , but I don't know why it was not working before.... But now everything is working properly !!! I can go next step to make my app !!  Thank you everyone.