# How to configure Firebase Messaging with latest version in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was using the below line of code for firebase messaging configuration for flutter noticification configuration , but now after integrating to the latest version of the firebase messaging it is giving me error

CODE LINE

```
 messaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message){}
```

ERROR in DART Analysis

```
error: The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'.
```

Comment: could you please post the whole code you're using to configure firebase messaging.

Comment: Which version of Firebase messaging are you using ?

Comment: the latest ` firebase_messaging ^8.0.0-dev.10` from flutterfire link https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please check following example.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
            arguments: MessageArguments(message, true));
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
                //      one that already exists in example app.
                icon: 'launch_background',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
          arguments: MessageArguments(message, true));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 119):

**FirebaseMessaging.configure() was removed by the firebase team:**, per https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#messaging —

> **Reason:** The previous implementation of `configure()` caused unintended side effects if called multiple times (either to register a
> different handler or remove handlers). This change allows developers
> to be more explicit about registering handlers and removing them
> without affecting others via Streams.

Use `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage`  method to get messages

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
    });
```

Use `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` as a replacement for `onLaunch` and `onResume` handlers:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
          arguments: MessageArguments(message, true));
    });
```

Comment: I searched for a clear explanation for 2 hours and find it here instead of the docs and change logs

Comment: But this is automatically showing the push notification in iOS even if you want to avoid in some scenario. Please guide

Comment: where do we have to put this code for it to run every time user starts the app?

Answer (score 27):

Building on Jitesh's answer, for me implementation of `getInitialMessage` is needed to make the navigation works when the app is terminated (replacement for onLaunch)

```
    // workaround for onLaunch: When the app is completely closed (not in the background) and opened directly from the push notification
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('getInitialMessage data: ${message.data}');
      _serialiseAndNavigate(message);
    });

    // onMessage: When the app is open and it receives a push notification
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessage data: ${message.data}");
    });

    // replacement for onResume: When the app is in the background and opened directly from the push notification.
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessageOpenedApp data: ${message.data}');
      _serialiseAndNavigate(message);
    });
```

Comment: Perfect explaination for old users! Now I got the onMessageOpenedApp

Comment: thankyou, I can't find this information anywhere

Comment: Please after printing `message.data` it gives me an empty map, I don't know why

Comment: @Samuel are you sending the data inside the [payload notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload)? Try printing message.notification to validate if you are handling the notification

Comment: Please , getInitialMessage return null message when I click on the notification when app is closed , do you know why ?

Answer (score 2):

After some tests, here are my conclusions :

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message)){} == "OLD" onResume()
ONLY activated when app is launched and/or in background and notification click

FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() == "OLD" onLaunch()
ONLY works when app was killed ! and notification clicked

Answer (score 0):

**Updated One:**

***FirebaseMessagingService*** is important to get started in the beginning of app. And for that sake, you need to follow this:
Declare this function first :

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  debugPrint("Firebase Messaging firebase is initialized");
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
```

And call this function in the main(){} of app:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

And then you will be able to use these functions:

**FirebaseMessaging.onMessage**  method to get messages

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
    });
```

**FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp** as a replacement for onLaunch and onResume handlers.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
          arguments: MessageArguments(message, true));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Event handling:**

Event handling has been reworked to provide a more intuitive API for developers. Foreground-based events can now be accessed via Streams:

**FirebaseMessaging.onMessage** Returns a Stream called when an incoming FCM payload is received whilst the Flutter instance is in the foreground, containing a [RemoteMessage].

**FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp** Returns a [Stream] that is called when a user presses a notification displayed via FCM. This replaces the previous onLaunch and onResume handlers.

**FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()** Sets a background message handler to trigger when the app is in the background or terminated.
IosNotificationSettings:

Answer (score 0):

i know the changes about the .configure() onlaunch/onresume methods.
they were replaced by

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
          arguments: MessageArguments(message, true));
    });
```

but this ONLY works when the app is still in background !
it won't work if the app was killed.
how to achieve this ?
What is the "new" equivalent for onLaunch() method please ?

Comment: You need to create a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you are afraid that it will be considered as duplicate, then kindly explain the difference along with the link of that question.

Comment: i already did it here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76522968/firebase-messaging-onmessageopenedapp-listen-doesnt-work-when-app-killed
thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes i did all that ^^
And everything works BUT the redirection on a Notification clic when the app was killed.
I do assure that the onMessageOpenedApp.listen() doesn't work when the app was killed.

The proof is that i have a screen that makes an historic of all notifications received and the one that are received in background whenn app was killed are :

- received and shown
- persisted and shown in the historic screen

When the app was killed and you click on a notification the onMessageOpenedApp CAN'T be fired (as onLaunch() / onResume() worked before...).

That's why i asked how to achieve this with new version of Firebase ?