# How can I handle IOS push notification?

Tags: flutter, apple-push-notifications

I have only been working on Android push notification, Now I want to work on IOS , I have all the required fields like developer account etc covered. I can in fact receive a push notification but as I click on it i want a dialogue box to open `retrieveRideRequestInfo` .The code below works fine with Android. However with IOS nothing happens as I am unsure what else is needed because the documentation is too complicated for me.

```
class PushNotificationService {
  FirebaseMessaging firebasemessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  Future initialize(context) async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message
          .notification; 
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
    
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message.data)!, context);
        

        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(),
            android:
               
                AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
                    channelDescription: channel.description,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    playSound: false,
                    icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
          ),
        );
        print('AndroidNotification after clicking ' + notification.title!);
        print('AndroidNotification after clicking ' + notification.body!);
        print("This is message map");

     
      }
    });

    //on message open
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // same as above
      RemoteNotification? notification = message
          .notification; //assign two variables for remotenotification and android notification
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        // if (doublenotification.isOdd)
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message.data)!, context);
      
        print('AndroidNotification after clicking ' + notification.title!);
        print('AndroidNotification after clicking ' + notification.body!);

        //getRideRequestId();
      }
      //}
    });
  }
```

The docs specify `if (notification != null && android != null) {}`  which is only taking care of android, How can I handle Ios notifications then ?

Answer (score 1):

You only added condition for `android` platform. you need also add for iOS platform. also make sure both

```
// onMessage: When the app is open and it receives a push notification
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;

    if (notification != null) {
      if (notification.android != null) {
        //---- Android notification open app handle here ----
        print("${notification.data}");
      } else {
        //---- iOS notification open app handle here ----
        print("${notification.data}");
      }
    }
});
```

> Also check **`notification.data`** before map into your widget because its slightly different.
> from from Android.

Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65056272/how-to-configure-firebase-messaging-with-latest-version-in-flutter#:%7E:text=accessed%20via%20Streams%3A-,FirebaseMessaging.,a%20notification%20displayed%20via%20FCM.) for firebase config.