# Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using version 6.0.16 of the FCM and it is marking the following error
Default notification channel metadata is missing in AndroidManifest.
Here is part of my Androidmanifest.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428612/missing-default-notification-channel-metadata-in-androidmanifest-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

You [need to add](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) the following metadata element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` within the application component:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

> From Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, [notification
> channels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)
> are supported and recommended. FCM provides a default notification
> channel with basic settings. If you prefer to
> [create](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateChannel)
> and use your own default channel, set
> **`default_notification_channel_id`** to the ID of your notification channel object as shown; FCM will use this value whenever incoming
> messages do not explicitly set a notification channel. To learn more,
> see [Manage notification channels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels).