# set custom Sound from only my application in push notification android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, ringtone

I need to set `custom sound` for `only my application`. I've assigned a custom ringtone from my storage to be used in notifications.

**What did I try...**

```java
(NotificationChannel) channel.setSound(Uri.parse("MY_PATH"), audio_atrr);
```

```java
(NotificationCompact.Builder) mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("MY_PATH"));
```

```java
(Notification) mNotification.sound = Uri.parse("MY_PATH");
```

It's useless for me, my device always plays the default sound when a notification is coming. what can i do?

Comment: did you checked this - [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71159936/14682570) and add some info like what Android version you tested,notifcation from firebase or locally.

Comment: Yes but my situation is set ringtone from application